# How to use GradientDescentOptimizer?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2])
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    session.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        sess.run(train_op)
        print x.eval(), loss.eval()
```

I have the above code. When I run it, I got the following error. I'd like to optimize `x`. I don't understand why it says there is no variable to optimize. Could anybody help me understand what is wrong and how to use `GradientDescentOptimizer` correctly? Thanks.

```
$ ./main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 8, in <module>
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 343, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 408, in compute_gradients
    raise ValueError("No variables to optimize.")
ValueError: No variables to optimize.
```

Comment: x is just a placeholder. You need to feed data into x, like a numpy array.

Comment: You are not feeding any value to `x` in the `sess.run()` part. If there is no value provided to it, what would the gradient descent optimize?

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error, you haven't defined any variables which will be trained at training time in your model, `x` is just a placeholder.